# Linear Mapping Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: U \to V$ be a linear isomorphism (meaning that $T$ is a linear map and also bijective).  Let $T^{-1}: V \to U$ be the inverse bijection of $T$.  Show that $T^{-1}$ is also linear.

Any clue here? No idea where to start.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1, v_2$ belong to $V$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar then there exist unique $u_1$ and $u_2$ lying in $U$ for which $Tu_1 = v_1$ and $Tu_2 = v_2.$ Then $T^{-1}(v_1 + \alpha v_2) = T^{-1}(T(u_1 + \alpha u_2)) = u_1 + \alpha u_2 = T^{-1} v_1 + \alpha T^{-1} v_2.$ QED

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide some hints for know:

Recall the two properties that must hold for a transformation to be bijevtive, and prove each separately.

You will need to use the properties of T being bijective, AND the existence of an inverse.